# how to confirm that netty has tried to read the socket

Tags: netty

I'd like to confirm from netty that a read event has occured before I close a connection.  It doesn't matter if it actually read in bytes, or an error occured.

From digging through netty code,  I don't believe the following guarantees order of operations:

```
channel.read();
channel.close();
```

Since a read event isn't a "task" in netty's event loop, there is a possibility that the close task will execute before the read event.

There is no "Read future" that can be used.  So my question is:  what is the best way to guarantee a read event occurs before closing a channel?"

If auto-read is used: If netty is currently in it's task loop writing data over the wire, and we call channel.close() will a read operation occur or will the close happen first?

Comment: Would you share the code so far please?

Comment: This explanation makes sense to me; it's more a question about Netty's design than about a specific bit of code that's using Netty. @DonCruickshank what information do you think is missing?

Answer (score 2):

In Netty, `read()` and `flush()` are special operations which do not return a `ChannelFuture`.  It's because the outcome of the `read()` operation is `channelRead()`, `channelReadComplete()`, or `exceptionCaught()`.  `flush()` operation doesn't have a `ChannelFuture` because it always is accompanied by `write()`, and you get the future there.

Therefore, to see if the data was actually read from the socket, you can see if your handler's `channelRead()` was invoked.

On the other hand, by default, Netty has `ChannelOption.AUTO_READ` turned on, so you don't need to call `read()` at all.  It just reads as soon as the connection becomes active.

Comment: Understood, but those only happen if data was actually read. Is there any way to know that we _tried_ to read, but no data was available? Or, alternatively, is there another way to see if data may be available other than attempting to read it?

The proximate issue is [a pull request for an APNs client](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy/pull/17) following [auto-close changes in Netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1952).

Comment: channelReadComplete looks interesting and from looking at the code it always gets fired regardless of the numbers of bytes read (or exception thrown).   @trustin can you confirm this is the case?

Comment: Regarding autoread:  If netty is currently in it's task loop writing data over the wire, and we call `channel.close()`  will a read operation occur or will the close happen first?

Comment: @trustin @AndrewSchmidt I created a simple test app to try this out, and it didn't seem to work. Requesting a read didn't trigger a call to either the `channelReadComplete` or `exceptionCaught` methods. It's possible that I'm screwing something up, though; the sample app is at https://gist.github.com/jchambers/7487099.